# Python | How to add a header to the csv file while creating it?

Tags: python, csv, header, file-handling

I am parsing hex data being obtained from a pipeline. The data is being parsed line-by-line and written to a csv file. I need to add the header.
So data obtained:

```
a b c d e....iy
f g h i j....iy
```

Required format:

```
1 2 3 4 5....259
a b c d e....iy
f g h i j....iy
```

I had tried writerow function. As it is line-by-line parsing, data obtained is as follows:

```
1 2 3 4 5....259
a b c d e....iy
1 2 3 4 5....259
e f g h i....iy
```

It prints the header name after every line.

The code I am currently using to print data to file is as below:

```
if '[' in line:
   #processdata functions(converting from hex)
   line = processdata
   f = open("output.csv", "a+")
   f.write(line)
   f.close()
```

I'd appreciate it if there are any suggestions regarding this for line-to-line parsing of the file.
I am looking for something like open("file.csv", "a+", header = ['1', '2','3','n']. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas

> file.to_csv("gfg2.csv", header=headerList, index=False)

```
# importing python package 
import pandas as pd 
  
# read contents of csv file 
file = pd.read_csv("gfg.csv") 
print("\nOriginal file:") 
print(file) 
  
# adding header 
headerList = ['id', 'name', 'profession'] 
  
# converting data frame to csv 
file.to_csv("gfg2.csv", header=headerList, index=False) 
  
# display modified csv file 
file2 = pd.read_csv("gfg2.csv") 
print('\nModified file:') 
print(file2)
```

see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-a-header-to-a-csv-file-in-python/

and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html